Behavior when connected to a USB-C docking station
This feels little but I am again at a loss
I just installed 24.04 onto a Dell 7490 which went well
I got a Dell WD19DCS USB-C docking station
and two external monitors
all kinda works except one thing
lid closed on the laptop
I don't see the bios boot, or the prompt for the disk encryption, or the user/pass screen they are all on the built-in laptop screen
I have to open the lid to the laptop and interact with the laptop directly
then..
I went into the displays and disabled the built-in screen
which moves the primary to one of the external monitors which is fine but none of this happens until after the boot process completes..
Oh and for the folks that want to know
I am cheap and buy mostly used refurbished laptops online so that's why i have an old/new 7490
even got it 24.04 to install on UEFI and enabled secure boot too..
but the boot thing is annoying..
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-08-01 12:05:38

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Dell Inc. Latitude 7490
Memory:                                      32.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i7-8650U × 8
Graphics:                                    Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
Disk Capacity:                               (null)

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            1.38.0
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-39-generic

12Aug2024
ok progress
I read these URLs
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2473462
Force gdm login screen to the primary monitor
Force gdm login screen to the primary monitor
and
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config/monitors.xml
sudo chown gdm:gdm /var/lib/gdm3/.config/monitors.xml
and now after I unlock the hd encryption, which is still on the laptop screen, I do get my gnome login/pass on the external monitors..
anyone know how to get the HD encryption prompt to show on the external monitors, or even on all monitors.  I am not even seeing the external monitors have a signal until the HD is opened and OS boots..
I mean I can keep doing this work around,
waiting a suitable amount of time,
then blindly type in the HD password, and
hope I then get passed along to the GDM login
But it just feels cludgy, ya know?
Marion
same question posted here
Behavior when connected to a USB-C docking station
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2499566
and
https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/latitude/7490-behavior-when-docked-to-wd19dcs/66abe87347effa74c4831ab2
13Aug2024
and i can interrupt the boot process to look at the bios
hit Fn F8 and switch the bios screen to the external monitor
exit the bios
and the freaking bootsplash is now on the external monitor
but it doesnt keep doing that after I power off and reboot..
its like it knows 'how' to do it right but just won't for some reason..
it feels like I am talking to myself some days.. :-)

Similar thing happens when I boot up my work computer (Windows  10) - I have to enter a bios password using the internal keyboard and it only shows on the internal screen, then - when Windows starts - the external keyboard and screen work. The point is, this is nothing to do with Ubuntu (or whatever OS is installed - which hasn’t even loaded at this stage). You won’t get an answer from this site as it’s nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Weird that, I gave up on Ubuntu 24.04 and re-installed 22.04.4 and it all works as advertised.. I didnt have to do anything for it to display the HD password on all available screens.  Crazy ain't it..  I guess 24.04 is a work in progress huh?
oh and too true i got no useful answer from the forum.

Downgrade to 22.04.4 solved the issue stated above.
